# Why cannot call the div #popup1?

Tags: php

Why cannot call the div #popup1?  I want to pass the $row['staffId'] to div and call the popup to show the information .

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Staff WHERE companyId='$companyIdResult'");

echo "<div>
<table >";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td >" . $row['staffName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['staffPhone'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td><a class ='editbutton' href=' #popup1?edit_id=".$row['staffId'] ."'>Edit</a></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}


echo "</table>";
echo "</div>";

if($_GET['edit_id'] != ""){
   $staffId = $_GET['edit_id'];

$sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM Staff WHERE staffId='".$staffId."'");
echo '<div id="popup1" class="overlay" >';
echo '<div class="popup">';
echo '<input type="text" name="staffName" value= ".$row['staffName']." ><br>';
echo '<input type="text" name="staffPhone" value=".$row['staffPhone']."><br>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: what is the question ?

Comment: Are you getting an error of some sort? Please show us.

Comment: it was not any response when i clicked the button

Comment: Don't use the deprecated and insecure `mysql_*`-functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7 (in 2015). Use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: **You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)** and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries, which can be used if you use the above mentioned MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: @shring you want open modal popup on edit click with data belongs to id.

Comment: if this is bootstrap you are missing `data-toggle="modal"` and  data-target="#popup1"` if not you need to show us the js u using

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile if this modal then this attribute will required.

Comment: If not the Op need to show us the js he's using to open the popup,.. @MohitKumar

Answer (score 1):

First of all you cannot append query parameters (`?edit_id=...`) to an anchor like `#popup1`, also you seem to misunderstand how PHP and the browser interact, you cannot open a popup and create it dynamically on the server side the way you seem to plan to. You could use AJAX to load the matching form for the staffId into your popup or generate a popup for every staffId beforehand (and create matching links with different anchors), but you try to open a popup1 with values generated on the server side and that doesn't work in this way.